# Trying to cast nparray to dataframe using pandas - hitting the error - the truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: pandas

Trying to do the below. I am trying to use simpleimputer below to replace median value for numeric columns and most frequent value for string columns in one step.

Even when i use copy=False, the simpleImputer doesnt seem to be do in place transformation of the data in the data frame. So, i had assign the data back to the same dataframe. However, it needs casting to dataframe when calling fit_transform. I had success in doing that when dtypes are not provided. But it means all resulting columns become of the type "object". When i provide the dtype list using the statement below, i hit the error below.

```
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent",copy=False)

train_X = pd.DataFrame(data=imp.fit_transform(train_X),columns=train_X.columns,dtype=train_X.dtypes)
```

Receiving the error below:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Below is the full stack trace

```
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
            <ipython-input-9-7463949bd70b> in <module>()
                  1 imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent",copy=False)
                  2 #print(train_X.columns)
            ----> 3 train_X = pd.DataFrame(data=imp.fit_transform(train_X),columns=train_X.columns,dtype=train_X.dtypes)
                  4 #imp.fit_transform(train_X)
                  5 '''train_X['FireplaceQu'].fillna(train_X['FireplaceQu'].value_counts().index[0])

            ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
                337             data = {}
                338         if dtype is not None:
            --> 339             dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)
                340 
                341         if isinstance(data, DataFrame):

            ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _validate_dtype(self, dtype)
                166 
                167         if dtype is not None:
            --> 168             dtype = pandas_dtype(dtype)
                169 
                170             # a compound dtype

            ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py in pandas_dtype(dtype)
               2020     # which we safeguard against by catching them earlier and returning
               2021     # np.dtype(valid_dtype) before this condition is evaluated.
            -> 2022     if dtype in [object, np.object_, 'object', 'O']:
               2023         return npdtype
               2024     elif npdtype.kind == 'O':

            ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
               1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
               1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
            -> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
               1577 
               1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

            ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback, as well as the final error? I suspect the error might come from a different line of code.

Comment: full stack trace provided